# Find unique rows in a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I know this question has been answered. But I do not understand something in the code. I am trying to find unique rows in a numpy array. The solution using structured arrays given as follows:

`x` is your input array‍

```
‍‍‍‍‍‍y = np.ascontiguousarray(x).view(np.dtype((np.void, x.dtype.itemsize * x.shape[1])))
_, idx = np.unique(y, return_index=True)
unique_result = x[idx]
```

My question is that why we need this line:

```
y = np.ascontiguousarray(x).view(np.dtype((np.void, x.dtype.itemsize * x.shape[1])))
```

why cannot we use only:

```
_, idx = np.unique(x, return_index=True)
unique_result = x[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a couple of questions. I am not sure where you found the solution you mention but I will explain why that probably was done. This:

```
_, idx = np.unique(x, return_index=True)
unique_result = x[idx]
```

does not work to find unique rows in an `np.array` because `np.unique` will flatten the given array if no axis is given. I then imagine that the `y = np.ascontiguousarray(x).view(np.dtype((np.void, x.dtype.itemsize * x.shape[1])))` line was added so that, even when flattened, the inner arrays, which they are trying to compare, would each be represented as individual items (of type void). Then, using `np.unique` would indeed return unique rows.

However, I do not see why any of that is necessary. You can just use `unique` directly while passing the axis you are interested in:

```
unique_result = np.unique(x, axis=0)
```